# How to write diagonal spaced print pattern in python

Tags: python

if n=2

```
* *
 * *
* *
 * *
```

if n=3

```
*  *  *
 *  *  *
  *  *  *
*  *  *
 *  *  *
  *  *  *
*  *  *
 *  *  *
  *  *  *
```

This code i written for. But this code is half this only print row and column not space condition.

```
n = int(input (": "))
i = 0
for i in range (n**2):
    j = 0
    for j in range (n):
        j+=1
        print ("* " , end="")
    i+=1
    print ("")
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem?

Comment: I edit the question, now it's extremely clear see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `i = 0`, `i += 1`, `j = 0`, and `j += 1`. These operations happen by default in `for` loops.

```
n = int(input(": "))
for i in range(n ** 2):

    for k in range(i % n):
        print(" ", end="")

    for j in range(n):
        print("* ", end="")

    print("")
```

Or you can make your string first, then print it:

```
n = int(input(": "))
for i in range(n ** 2):
    line = ((i % n) * ' ') + (n * '* ')
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with the answer given by [@ChamRun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14761615/chamrun), just an aesthetic finesse:

```py
for i in range(n ** 2):
    line = ((i % n) * ' ') + (n * '* ')
    print(line[:-1])  # remove last char
```

this removes the last space from the print (which is perhaps not required for this pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
n=3 #input as you will
for k in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(" "*(i),end='')
        for j in range(n):
            print("* ",end="")
        print("\n",end='')
```